# how to manage multiple state using ui-router in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular-ui-router

I'm working on a project using angularjs with nodejs as backend, i'm building a single page application(spa) in angularjs for that.
so, I need your help at one point which is that there are two state for example state A and it's sub state aa (it is related to my project).
all the state share a common controller which is on main template file,
okay.
Now come on the point i want to upload a file code is written in sub state aa template file, when i access that file variable using scope from the controller then i console it undefined. i don't understand why i showing it undefined, but when i apply controller separately on sub state aa then it console the file value. but why it doing so, i don't want that, please anybody help me to out come from this problem.

> Here is my code of state aa which is using for file upload

```
<div>
<input type = "file" file-model = "avatarFile"/>
</div>
```

for file upload i'm using a directive that give me the file as like below

```
app.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;

            element.bind('change', function () {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

> and at last my main template code is here

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<body ng-controller="lugbeeSPACtrl">
<div ui-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and i'm want to also tell that state A template is also in a separate html file.
if any help is needed regrading to understand this question then please information but please solve my problem. thank you.

Comment: Can you post where your states are set up?

Comment: @Sophie my states are in run method in app.js

Comment: What does it look like?

Comment: @Sophie Thank you for your effort, i solved the problem i used rootscope instead of scope to save the file in the directive, so i can access it anywhere. if you know another solution please tell me